# Conflict on loading library libstdc++.so.6 with Tkinter and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, libstdc++

I am using `Tkinter` in Python to handle the `SpirentTestCenter` API with `Tcl` code. I happen to use `pandas` as well and when used together, I am facing the library load issue.

```
import os
sStcVersion='4.73'
sStdPath = '/repo/dinesh/MY_PACKAGES/STC/'+sStcVersion
import pandas as pd
import Tkinter


tcl = Tkinter.Tcl()
tcl.eval('puts $::env(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)')
tcl.eval('source '+'/repo/dinesh/MY_PACKAGES/STC/'+sStcVersion+'/pkgIndex.tcl')
tcl.eval('package require SpirentTestCenter 4.73')

>>> Error Occured while loading the Spirent Automation Internal Utility Library (couldn't load file "/repo/MY_PACKAGES/STC/4.73/libsTcl.so": 
/repo/dinesh/MY_PACKAGES/robot/PACKAGES/lib_for_64bit_compat/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /repo/MY_PACKAGES/STC/4.73/libsTcl.so)).
```

The required `libstdc++.so.6` is located in the same directory as `libsTcl.so` (i.e./repo/MY_PACKAGES/STC/4.73/). But it is taking the `libstdc++.so.6` from the another directory which is available in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I tried changing the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` , but still it is taking it from the incorrect directory.

If I don't import the `pandas` module, this issue is not seen. It seems like the `libstdc++.so.6` is loaded already with pandas from `/repo/dinesh/MY_PACKAGES/robot/PACKAGES/lib_for_64bit_compat/libstdc++.so.6`.

How can I force python to take the `libstdc++.so.6` from the preferred directory ?

Answer (score 1):

> But it is taking the libstdc++.so.6 from the another directory which is available in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I tried changing the LD_LIBRARY_PATH , but still it is taking it from the incorrect directory.

That suggests that either it's not getting it from LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or you didn't change LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly.

You could try setting `LD_PRELOAD=/repo/MY_PACKAGES/STC/4.73/libstdc++.so.6` in the environment, to load the desired version before anything else, so that when the loader sees a dependency to `libstdc++.so.6` it already has the right one and won't try loading the wrong one.